# Apply proxy gateway in Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, desiredcapabilities

My goal is to apply a proxy gateway (eg. geosurf.io) inside of the Selenium webdriver.

1. I need to do it thru using *DesiredCapabilities*, since it seems *DesiredCapabilities* being the only way for plugging in proxy [gateway] ([source](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)).
2. *DesiredCapabilities* functionality works at Selenium Grid (not just in a plain Selenium server). [Selenium Grid docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp).
3. I've successfully run Selenium Grid at a local Windows 10 machine.
   [image]
4. So, I've composed the following code to apply *DesiredCapabilities* and proxy gateway for capabilities used in Selenium webdriver:

   ```
   import requests
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
   PROXY = "gw1.geosurf.io:8080" # my account at geosurf.io, port 8080 - Germany

   from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
   proxy_object = Proxy()
   proxy_object.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
   proxy_object.http_proxy = PROXY
   proxy_object.socks_proxy = PROXY
   proxy_object.ssl_proxy = PROXY

   keep_alive = True
   browser_profile=None

   webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX = {
       "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
       "autodetect":False,
       "platform": "WIN10"
   }
   driver = webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.43.98:5566/grid/register", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, browser_profile, proxy_object, keep_alive)
   ```

I've forced some output of what is inside of webdriver.py (*C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py*) when running the above code, in the `__init__`:

```
command_executor:  http://192.168.43.98:5566/grid/register
capabilities: 
{'autodetect': False,
 'class': 'org.openqa.selenium.Proxy',
 'platform': 'WIN10',
 'proxy': {'httpProxy': 'gw1.geosurf.io:8080',
           'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
           'socksProxy': 'gw1.geosurf.io:8080',
           'sslProxy': 'gw1.geosurf.io:8080'}}
```

Yet the **problem turned to be in `webdriver.py`**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\RnD\captcha-test\test_geosurf_proxy_gateway.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.43.98:5566/grid/register", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, browser_profile, proxy_object, keep_alive)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 191, in start_session
    self.session_id = response['sessionId']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The error, *TypeError: string indices must be integers*, seems being not `proxy gateway` type, nor `DesiredCapabilities`'s settings related.

When outputting at line 190, the `response` variable being a string, contaning html snippet:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze('{"version":"3.4.0","type":"Grid Node","consoleLink":"/wd/hub"}');
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

How to resolve this `webdriver.py` issue?

### Update

When further debugging `webdriver.py` I output `response` varible right after `response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)`:

```
{'status': 0,
 'value': u'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <meta charset="UTF-8">\n  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>\n  <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />\n  <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>\n  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>\n  <script type="text/javascript">\n    var json = Object.freeze(\'{"version":"3.4.0","type":"Grid Node","consoleLink":"/wd/hub"}\');\n  </script>\n</head>\n<body>\n\n<div id="content">\n  <div id="help-heading">\n    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>\n    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>\n  </div>\n\n  <div id="content-body">\n    <p>\n      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.\n    </p>\n    <p>\n      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the\n      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.\n      <span id="console-item">\n        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.\n      </span>\n    </p>\n    <p>\n      Happy Testing!\n    </p>\n  </div>\n\n  <div>\n    <footer id="help-footer">\n      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from\n      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our\n      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.\n   </footer>\n  </div>\n </div>\n\n</body>\n</html>'}
```

Why doesn't it contain `sessionId` key-value ?

### Update 2

My partial success was to run

```
`driver = webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.43.98:5566/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, browser_profile, proxy_object, keep_alive)`
```

as the last line of the script. It has produced the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\RnD\captcha-test\test_geosurf_proxy_gateway.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.43.98:5566/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, browser_profile, proxy_object, keep_alive)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 193, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 265, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{proxy={httpProxy=gw1.geosurf.io:8080, proxyType=MANUAL, socksProxy=gw1.geosurf.io:8080, sslProxy=gw1.geosurf.io:8080}, autodetect=false, class=org.openqa.selenium.Proxy, platform=WIN10}]
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-78JS3VQ', ip: '192.168.43.98', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance (DefaultDriverFactory.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (None:-1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)
```

changing proxy address to `localhost:8080` has brought the same error...

### Update 3

I've succesded to launch/open the node console manually at browser http://192.168.43.98:5566/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html
[image]

Yet, the only session I could load was of Chrome browser 
[image]

No success to load FireFox or IE 10 browser sessions as possible for this Grid:
[image]

I do not know if it's helpful of how to manage Grid nodes for external proxies plugging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I could have opened Chrome browser instance with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
PROXY = "gw1.geosurf.io:8080" # 8080 - Germany

from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
proxy_object = Proxy()
proxy_object.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy_object.http_proxy = PROXY
proxy_object.socks_proxy = PROXY
proxy_object.ssl_proxy = PROXY

keep_alive = True
browser_profile=None

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities['class'] = "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy"
capabilities['platform'] = "WINDOWS"
capabilities['version'] = "10"
capabilities["autodetect"]= False

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.43.98:5566/wd/hub", capabilities, browser_profile, proxy_object, keep_alive)
driver.get('http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/recaptcha')
raw_input('Press any key to quit Selenium driver: ')
driver.quit()
```

Yet, the opened browser instanse is not able to load any content...